# How to extract the direction of a point on a path in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am following some tips online to extract a certain point on a path as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,color}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0,2) to[out=-90,in=0] coordinate[pos=0.28](A)(-3,-1);
     \draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90] (A);
     \fill[blue] (A) circle (2pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Where A is the point of interest. I would like to draw another path that exact on the top of the given curve but just cover from (0,2) to A in red. To do so, I need to know the "in" direction at point A. I use asymptote before and it has a dir command to extract the direction of a path at a certain point, but I didn't see it in tikz.

p.s. Someone recommend me to redraw the path from (0,2) to A and from A to (-3,1) so I can control the direction at A. For my case, I would like to know a more generic method to extract the direction so I could program it for other complicate cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pgfplots library `fillbetween` has the option of accessing intersection segments. However, here you could just clip the relevant stretch of the path. To make things more convenient, one can use `save path` and `use path` to recycle the path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[save path=\pathA] (0,2) coordinate (start) to[out=-90,in=0] coordinate[pos=0.28](A)(-3,-1);
   \draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90] (A);
   \begin{scope}
    \clip[overlay] let \p1=($(A)-(start)$),\n1={veclen(\x1,\y1)} in
      (start) circle[radius=\n1];
    \draw[orange,thick,use path=\pathA];
   \end{scope}
   \fill[blue] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively you can place `A` with `decorations.markings` and read out the rotation angle from the transformation matrix. (Note that things become more complicated if you scale x and y differently. Note also that this will in general not restore the precise sub path since a curve is not completely fixed by the in and out angles, there is also a looseness parameter.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \path (0,0) coordinate (O) (1,0) coordinate (X);
   \draw[postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position 0.28 with {\coordinate(A);
    \pgfgettransformentries\tmpA\tmpB\tmpC\tmp\tmp\tmp
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrot}{atan2(\tmpB,\tmpA)+180}%
    \xdef\myrot{\myrot}%
    }}] 
     (0,2) coordinate (start) to[out=-90,in=0] (-3,-1);
   \draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90] (A);
   \draw[orange,thick] (start)  to[out=-90,in=\myrot] (A)
   node[right]{in angle is $\myrot^\circ$};
   \fill[blue] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A more core level option is to use `\pgfpathcurvebetweentime` from p. 1095 of the pgfmanual v3.1.5. Here is a very basic option that uses the `show path construction` decoration to get the curve start, end and control points in. This can be made more Ti*k*Zy, of course, but here is the basic thing. The `subcurve` style takes three parameters: a set of pgf instructions that indicate what to do with the path, the start time and the end time.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{subcurve/.style n args=3{decoration={show path construction, 
moveto code={},
lineto code={},
curveto code={
\typeout{\tikzinputsegmentfirst}
\path (\tikzinputsegmentfirst) coordinate (tikzinputsegmentfirst)
(\tikzinputsegmentsupporta) coordinate (tikzinputsegmentsupporta)
(\tikzinputsegmentsupportb) coordinate (tikzinputsegmentsupportb)
(\tikzinputsegmentlast) coordinate (tikzinputsegmentlast);
\pgfpathcurvebetweentime{#2}{#3}{\pgfpointanchor{tikzinputsegmentfirst}{center}}%
{\pgfpointanchor{tikzinputsegmentsupporta}{center}}%
{\pgfpointanchor{tikzinputsegmentsupportb}{center}}%
{\pgfpointanchor{tikzinputsegmentlast}{center}}%
#1
\pgfusepath{stroke}
},
closepath code={}
},decorate}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \path (0,0) coordinate (O) (1,0) coordinate (X);
   \draw[postaction={subcurve={\pgfsetstrokecolor{red}\pgfsetlinewidth{1pt}}{0}{0.28}}] 
     (0,2) coordinate (start) to[out=-90,in=0] 
     coordinate[pos=0.28](A)(-3,-1);
   %\draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90] (A);
   \fill[blue] (A) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is very neat but I still want to know if there is any way to find the direction of the curve at point A, since I need the direction for other computation and drawing.

Comment: @user1285419 I added a version that does that.

Comment: Thanks. I try to use the computed angle at A to redraw the curve and you will see that it is not overlapping on the top of the original curve very well.
\draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90,in=\myrot] (A); and your drawing in orange show the minor offset as well.

Comment: @user1285419 Yes, as I wrote the curve is not completely specified by the in and out angles. If you use `\draw [red] (0,2) to[out=-90,in=\myrot,looseness=0.9] (A);` it will match. The angles is correct, I believe, but if you take a subpath you need also to adjust the looseness.